# onClick event Submits form automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form on my page and a button with id "calculate" in the form. When I press the button it will do some calculations using a function. But when I press the button it behaves like a submit button and sends the data. I don't want to send the form, I just want to calculate.

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_add_data">
...
<button class="btn btn-info" id="calculate" onclick="calculate()"> Calculate </button>
...
</form>
```

Comment: noob mistake, any click on a form button defaults to submit. you must specify the `type` of your button https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Button#attr-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Event.preventDefault()`.

The `preventDefault()` method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur. For example, this can be useful when: Clicking on a "Submit" button, prevent it from submitting a form. Clicking on a link, prevent the link from following the URL.

In your situation:

```
document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
});
```

or:

```
// in your JS file
function calculate(event){
      event.preventDefault()
}
```

read more about it [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Answer (score 2):

Inside calculate function use:

```
function calculate(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    return false;
}
```

Prevent default will stop event propagation, and return false will keep the page from being refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

type="button" is the answer as you said.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="calculate" onclick="calculate()"> Calculate </button>
```